# Lock window position on display change

Tags: mfc, position, window, screen, display

I have an application which has several windows and I want that some of them (which I will call `CMyLockedFrameWndEx`, because they derive from `CFrameWndEx`) stay placed where they were after changing system display area. 
The Parent of all windows of my application is NULL.

I've managed to already catch the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message when I drag the position of the 2nd monitor relatively to the first; and I also had come to catch the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` when I connect or disconnect the 2nd monitor's HDMI cable. I've intercepted them both at `CMyLockedFrameWndEx::WindowProc`.

The automatic window repositioning occurs after that. I noticed that bacause I've put breakpoints on `CMyLockedFrameWndEx::OnWindowPosChanging` and `CMyLockedFrameWndEx::OnWindowPosChanged` and they stop after the events I catched on `WindowProc`. This workflow seems to be unrelated to the catching of events I described as my `WindowProc` method is:

```
LRESULT CMyLockedFrameWndEx::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_DISPLAYCHANGE)
    {
        TRACE(_T("DISPLAY CHANGE"));
        return 0L;
    }

    if (message == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
    {
        TRACE(_T("SYSCOMMAND"));

        if (wParam == SC_MOVE)
        {
            return 0L;
        }
    }

    if (message == WM_WININICHANGE)
    {
        TRACE(_T("WININICHANGE"));

        if (wParam == SPI_SETWORKAREA)
        {
            return 0L;
        }
    }



    return __super::WindowProc( message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and when passing in `OnWindowPosChanging` or `OnWindowPosChanged`, the flow doesn't come from the specific cases of `WindowProc` handled by me. And that is a problem.

I tried to follow the call stack to see what window sent the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` or the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message, but I didn't succeed. I have even tried to use Spy++64 to detect who was the the sender of the message, but I didn't succeed. The whole idea of seeing who was the sender was: if it is associated to a system's display change is to detect it beforehand and impeach the auto repositioning to even happen.

As i didn't succeed yet, what can I do to make the window immune to a system's display change?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain: what happens to a window positioned on the first screen at, for example, (100,100) when you connect the second screen? Does it move? Where to?

Comment: The problem is not there. The problem is when I disconnect the 2nd screen I do not want the system to automatically put the window on the 1st one. I want the window to continue at its position on the 2nd screen even if I disconnect the cable. Of course, it will be **HIDDEN**, but it is what I am searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unhappy news are I can not do this on a preventive way, because the system moves the windows to the primary screen even after sending any useful messages.

The good news are I can react to the move by adding a

`ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED()`

line on the class's message map and supply it with its respective handler function:

```
CMyLockedFrameWndEx::OnWindowPosChanged(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{
    __super::OnWindowPosChanged(lpwndpos);

    CFrameWndEx* pFrame=(CFrameWndEx*)::AfxGetMainWnd();
    VALIDATE_FPTR(pFrame);

    CMyDoc* pDoc=(CMyDoc*)pFrame->GetActiveDocument();
    VALIDATE_FPTR(pDoc);

    POSITION p= pDoc->GetFirstViewPosition();

    while(p)
    {
        CMyLockedView* pLockedView= dynamic_cast<CLockedView*>(pDoc->GetNextView(p));
        if(!pLockedView)
            continue;

        if(pLockedView->GetParentFrame() == this)
        {
            this->SetWindowPos(NULL, m_Top, m_Left, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);

            break;
        }
    }
}´
```

Note, that it helps me that I was persisting the position where the window was in the `m_Top` and `m_Left` variables.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is: you are, obviously, in control of the placement of your own window.

The bad news - Windows will **first** move your window to its new position, **then** send you the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` and `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, as seen in this Spy++'s log:

```
S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:003CF9AC
S WM_GETMINMAXINFO lpmmi:003CF624
R WM_GETMINMAXINFO lpmmi:003CF624
R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED lpwp:003CF9AC
S WM_MOVE xPos:278 yPos:450
R WM_MOVE
R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
S WM_SETTINGCHANGE wFlag:SPI_ICONVERTICALSPACING pszMetrics:0026E018
R WM_SETTINGCHANGE
S WM_DISPLAYCHANGE cBitsPerPixel:32 cxScreen:2560 cyScreen:1440
R WM_DISPLAYCHANGE
S WM_SETTINGCHANGE wFlag:SPI_SETWORKAREA pszMetrics:0026E018
R WM_SETTINGCHANGE
```

So - you would have to test the position changing to another screen by yourself. Like in this simplified example, where `2560` is my screen's width:

```
case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
{
    WINDOWPOS* pWP = (WINDOWPOS*)lParam;
    if ((pWP->flags & SWP_NOMOVE) == 0) // it's a move
    {
        if (pWP->x < 2560)
            pWP->flags |= SWP_NOMOVE;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't accept your answer yet because I could manage to do it using `ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED()` and its respective handler function `OnWindowPosChanged`

Comment: @sergiol - sorry, I don't understand... Did you manage or did you not?

Comment: I did, but not with your code. It is a bit similar, but I managed to do it using ``ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED()`` and its respective handler function ``OnWindowPosChanged``